# How to check other user's CRUD permission for an object (APEX)

Tags: apex, crud

I want to find out, if **another** user has READ permission on a specific object (I don't care about record access/sharing). Is there a way to accomplish this via APEX?

I do NOT want to find out if the *running* user has access to the object, since that is rather straight forward.

My use case is: I want to assign ownership of custom object records to users based on their properties. Unfortunately a user can only own a record if he has at least read access to the object. If I try to assign the owner regardless, I'll get an exception.

Also this must be applicable in a non-test context, so. runAs() won't do.

My question is: How can I check read (or CRUD in general) access to objects for other users?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you reframe your question with specific ask

Comment: @SantanuBoral done

Comment: If you are using permission sets, this might be a possible solution. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try like below

```
String desireUserId = UserInfo.getUserId(); // or pass any other user id.
User u = [select profileId from user where id =: desireUserId];
String profileId = u.profileId;

List<ObjectPermissions> 0bjPermissionList = [SELECT Id, SObjectType, 
PermissionsRead FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE parentid in (select id from 
permissionset where PermissionSet.Profile.Id=: profileId)];
```

Before assigning, chedk if that user has PermissoinsRead field is true.

Comment: While this does help to a majority extent, is there a way to not check this on a profile level? I mean I have read only users and editor users both sharing the same profile.